# CSS positioning with IE8 - expressions not supported

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
DIV#left
{
z-index: 100;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
DIV#right
{
z-index: 100;
position:absolute;
left:100px;
top:0px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #e20074;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="left">
1
</div>
<div id="right">
2
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

But I need the right div section to be expanded to the end of the page (width=100%)
So here is how I changed the width for DIV#right:

```
width: expression(parseInt(document.body.offsetWidth)-100);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with IE any more! IE8 and firefox ignore expressions. How can I overcome this issue?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh no, now you have to design webpages the right way!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use CSS expressions like that - they're slow, old, and most importantly, proprietary, meaning it won't work on anything other than IE.

Here's a simple solution that works on Firefox, IE8 and IE7 [but not IE6 though]: Give the right `div` a `right: 0` to force the `div` to expand out all the way to the end of the page:

```
#right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/hEeVY/

If you're using expressions for *anything*, it's probably better off to use Javascript to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @wa_liu No, I can't see that - that code playground thingy is only visible to you, since its not saved. If you need to show me anything, you can try using jsfiddle instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CSS Expressions are slow, they affect performance. Along with they they compromise with security as well. Solution specified by Yi Jiang must work.

Now all browsers will go on same terms. To know more on why Expressions were dropped please check http://techbookshelf.blogspot.in/2012/11/css-expressions-in-ie8-and-higher.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.